# Allowing null value in Peewee

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I'm trying to allow null values in some columns of a MySQL database using peewee with bottle. Looking at the docs [here](http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/models.html) I thought that would be quite easy. I set up a class like this:

```
class TestClass(MySQLModel):
Title = pw.CharField(null = True)
```

created the table and tried to insert a null value like this:

```
myDB.connect()
x = TestClass.create(Title = None)   
x.save()
```

Only for it to hang up on me and say "`_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1048, "Column 'Title' cannot be null")`". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You said that you "created the table". How exactly did you go about doing this?

Comment: `TestClass.create_table()`. Table is apparently created correctly, I don't show them in the question but I successfully inserted some none-null entries.

Comment: Oops, got it, when I originally made the table I created it as `(NULL = True)`, rather than `(null = True)`. Seems to work when I fix that. Thanks guys

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When table was created, said

```
Title = pw.Charfield(NULL = True)
```

rather than

```
Title = pw.Charfield(null = True)
```

Comment: Peewee will not drop or recreate your tables when you change code.  That would be quite disastrous if you had data.